# How to localize decimal numbers of an ordered lists?

Tags: html, css, localization, internationalization

Is there a way to display decimal numbers of an ordered list in language of the Website? For example I have an ordered list in a Farsi language Website (`<html lang="fa">`), but decimal numbers before each list item appear in English instead of in Farsi!

Markup example of an ordered list in Farsi:

```
<ol dir="rtl">
    <li>کتابهای زیادی در شصت و سه درصد گذشته</li>
    <li>چاپگرها و متون بلکه روزنامه و مجله</li>
    <li>لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی</li>
</ol>
```

https://codepen.io/smohadjer/pen/GBQVgr

Comment: Can you add an exemple ?

Comment: After your edit, I'd be interested to see the code that generates the list as described.

Comment: https://codepen.io/smohadjer/pen/GBQVgr

Comment: `list-style: persian`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for "list-style: arabic-indic;".

You can see all available styles here: https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/counter-style-demo/

There is also a draft spec to create your own symbols for numbered lists, but it is only supported in the latest Firefox so far. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style

Also a better reference for the list-style-type CSS attribute can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `list-style-type` attribute from CSS, then you can specify a range of numbering types and associate them with the `lang` attribute.

For example:

- armenian     The marker is traditional Armenian numbering
- cjk-ideographic  The marker is plain ideographic numbers
- decimal The marker is a number    decimal-leading-zero   The
- georgian The marker is traditional Georgian numbering
- hebrew   The marker is traditional Hebrew numbering
- hiragana     The marker is traditional Hiragana numbering
- hiragana-iroha   The marker is traditional Hiragana iroha numbering
- katakana     The marker is traditional Katakana numbering

etc

There is more information here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

And trial code here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_ol_list-style-type&preval=hiragana-iroha

Comment: I want the number to be decimal, but in language of the Website, not in English.